# MySQL: Selecting multiple fields into multiple variables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-function

Can I SELECT multiple columns into multiple variables within the same select query in MySQL?

For example:

```
DECLARE iId INT(20);
DECLARE dCreate DATETIME;

SELECT Id INTO iId, dateCreated INTO dCreate 
FROM products
WHERE pName=iName;
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Your [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) isn't quite right: you need to list the fields in order before the INTO, and the corresponding target variables after:

```
SELECT Id, dateCreated
INTO iId, dCreate
FROM products
WHERE pName = iName
```

Comment: +1.  This is a case where T-SQL syntax is clearer.  Having these as separate lists causes the same maintenance problem as DECLARE CURSOR and FETCH (not that I, uh, ever use those).

Comment: Same for Pl/Sql as well.

Answer (score 17):

==========Advise==========

@martin clayton Answer is correct, But this is an advise only.

Please avoid the use of ambiguous variable in the stored procedure.

Example :

```
SELECT Id, dateCreated
INTO id, datecreated
FROM products
WHERE pName = iName
```

The above example will cause an error (null value error)

Example give below is correct. I hope this make sense.

Example :

```
SELECT Id, dateCreated
INTO val_id, val_datecreated
FROM products
WHERE pName = iName
```

You can also make them unambiguous by referencing the table, like:

[  Credit : [maganap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619537/maganap) ]

```
SELECT p.Id, p.dateCreated INTO id, datecreated FROM products p 
WHERE pName = iName
```

Comment: You can also make them unambiguous by referencing the table, like: `SELECT p.Id, p.dateCreated
INTO id, datecreated
FROM products p
WHERE pName = iName`

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to Martin's answer, you could also add the INTO part at the end of the query to make the query more readable:

```
SELECT Id, dateCreated FROM products INTO iId, dCreate
```

Comment: @KusalDissanayake The question was asked for MySQL