# MySQL Stored Procedure variables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In MySQL I'm trying to write a Stored Procedure which does the following:

1. Run a SELECT query which returns 1 row with 2 columns (so two pieces of information).
2. Run an INSERT query which includes the two previous values returned and a few parameters which were passed into the stored procedure.

I was originally thinking I could store the two pieces of information from Step 1 into a variable, and then pass those into Step 2. After some reading though it seems that a variable in MySQL can only hold 1 piece of data. How can I get the 2 pieces of information from Step 1 into my INSERT statement in Step 2?

Thank you!

Comment: Look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450529/selecting-multiple-fields-into-multiple-variables-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**INSERT INTO ... SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html). 
Example,

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       value1, 
       value2 
FROM   table2
```

Here you select `col1`, `col2` from `table2` and add 2 new custom values `value1` and `value2` to the result set. This new 4 columns get inserted in to the `table1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use SELECT ... INTO clause, which will select values from specified table to variables you define in stored proc.

Refer to manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0):

create something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertThis(IN paramA varchar(50), IN paramB int, INT paramC varchar(50))
BEGIN
     INTO INTO tableB(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD)
     SELECT paramA as fieldA, paramB as fieldB, fieldC, fieldD
     FROM tableA
     WHERE fieldC = paramC;
END
```

Comment: `Where` condition is not needed here

Comment: It's only a sample bro. aside from using `LIMIT` what else can OP use to display 2 rows?